# Put child element down in second row by using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a toolbar with a title that is placed centered and will contains dynamically content. I have included the maximum number of characters for the title in my example. Now I want to add a little bit of responsiveness.

If the window gets too small to display all three child elements in one row, I want to have the title in second row across the whole width. The buttons of the `.navigation` should remain in the first row on the left side and the buttons of `.view-list` in the first row on the right side.

I'm new with using `display: flex;` and would like to know if the scenario above is possible?
I tried to modify CSS with `align-self`, `justify-content` and `order` but without any success so far.

My minfied code example looks like this:

```css
.toolbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.toolbox .navigation,
.toolbox .title,
.toolbox .view-list {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.toolbox .title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The styles below are only for the buttons and can be ignored */

.button-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-group::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group+.button-group {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.button-group .button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbox">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="button-group">
      <button class="button">A</button>
      <button class="button">B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button class="button">C</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="title">ABC DEFGH I JKL MNOPQRST WXYZ</h2>
  <div class="view-list">
    <div class="button-group">
      <button class="button">First</button>
      <button class="button">Second</button>
      <button class="button">Third</button>
      <button class="button">Fourth</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT additional question**

In the answers below we will work with the media-queries. Is there a solution without the using of `@media`?

The problem is the design. If the title contains only a few characters, it would be placed in a second row, even though it would fit between the buttons.

**UPDATE**
Since I haven't found a solution without media-queries myself, this is probably the solution. The only other method I could think of is to calculate with JavaScript and then manipulate the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles to change the order of the flex-item.

```
/* Styles to change the order of flex-item */
@media screen and (max-width: 858px) {
  .toolbox {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .navigation {
    order: 0;
  }

  .title {
    order: 2;
  }

  .view-list {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.toolbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.toolbox .navigation,
.toolbox .title,
.toolbox .view-list {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.toolbox .title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The styles below are only for the buttons and can be ignored */

.button-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-group::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group+.button-group {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.button-group .button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 12px;
}

/* Styles to change the order of flex-item */
@media screen and (max-width: 858px) {
  .toolbox {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .navigation {
    order: 0;
  }
  
  .title {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .view-list {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbox">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="button-group">
      <button class="button">A</button>
      <button class="button">B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button class="button">C</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="title">ABC DEFGH I JKL MNOPQRST WXYZ</h2>
  <div class="view-list">
    <div class="button-group">
      <button class="button">First</button>
      <button class="button">Second</button>
      <button class="button">Third</button>
      <button class="button">Fourth</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a great solution. Is there another solution to keep the styles dynamic and do it without the media-query?

Comment: @UfguFugullu I don't know if there is another solution without media query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media` to adjust the view for mobile users and order to update blocks position. I've just added the next to your code:

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .toolbox {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .toolbox :nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
    .toolbox :nth-child(2) {
        order: 3;
        flex: 1 0 100%;
    }
    .toolbox :nth-child(3) {order: 2;}
}
```

```css
.toolbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.toolbox .navigation,
.toolbox .title,
.toolbox .view-list {
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.toolbox .title {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* The styles below are only for the buttons and can be ignored */

.button-group {
    display: inline-block;
}

.button-group::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.button-group+.button-group {
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.button-group .button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .toolbox {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .toolbox :nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
    .toolbox :nth-child(2) {
        order: 3;
        flex: 1 0 100%;
    }
    .toolbox :nth-child(3) {order: 2;}
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbox">
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="button-group">
                    <button class="button">A</button>
                    <button class="button">B</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-group">
                    <button class="button">C</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="title">ABC DEFGH I JKL MNOPQRST WXYZ</h2>
            <div class="view-list">
                <div class="button-group">
                    <button class="button">First</button>
                    <button class="button">Second</button>
                    <button class="button">Third</button>
                    <button class="button">Fourth</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```